# Error in Exporting and importing Database in MariaDb from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Command Terminal

Tags: command-line, mysql, mariadb

I am new to Ubuntu. I have installed Xampp on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Can you please tell me, what is wrong with this Export database command ?

```
mysqldump - u root -p sachin_copy_db > /home/sachin/Downloads/cl14-sachin_db.sql;
```

Following is the error i am getting:

```
sachin@ubuntu:~$ /opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p
MariaDB [(none)]> mysqldump - u root -p sachin_copy_db >  /home/sachin/Downloads/cl14-sachin_db.sql;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You   
have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds    to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near    'mysqldump - u root -p sachin_copy_db >    /home/sachin/Downloads/cl14-sachin_db.sql' at line 1
```

Also i am getting error while importing database, Here is the error:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> mysql -u root -p sachin_copy_db < /home/sachin/Downloads/cl14-sachin_db.sql;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You
have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u root -p sachin_copy_db < /home/sachin/Downloads/cl14-sachin_db.sql' at line 1
```

Comment: AFAIK `mysqldump` is an external program - not a mysql command. You need to run it directly from the shell prompt, rather than from inside mysql.

Comment: fine Thanks, but can you let me know how can i use mysqldump from  Shell prompt. I mean to say i have to set classpath or i have to which external program etc. Please reply. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

These import and export data commands needs to be used  directly from command terminal like

Import Data Command

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p sachin_db_copy < /home/sachin/Downloads/cl134_sachin_db.sql;
```

Export Data Command

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump -u root -p sachin_db_copy > /home/sachin/Downloads/cl135_sachin_db.sql
```